# Reversing a motor after momentary switch is opened

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, motor, h-bridge, delay

I want to build a circuit that turns a DC motor clockwise when a momentary switch is held. After the momentary switch is released, the motor should run in anti-clockwise for a few seconds (3-5) before stopping. It is powered using 2 AA batteries.

This is the circuit I have so far:

[image]

The top part is a standard H bridge, and it is working correctly.

At the bottom half, I added a capacitor that could charge when the switch is closed(top left). Once the capacitor is charged, it should power the B MOSFETS (top right and bottom left) for a few seconds. The issue I am having is that while the switch is closed, the B MOSFETS are also getting powered through the battery along with the A MOSFETS. This will create a short.

My solution to preventing this situation was to add an inverter circuit that pulls the current away from the B pins. But this is also a short circuit.

So my question is: *How to block current from flowing through the B MOSFETS gates while also charging the capacitor. But once the switch is closed, the capacitor should power the B MOSFETS.*

All the components with source/drain are MOSFETS irfz44n.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I wouldn't have thought that those MOSFETs would be able to operate off of 3V.  If you're not married to the pushbutton switch, a DPDT version would work here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fthXgL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to be a momentary push button. As a complete noob in electronics, I dont even know if 'normally closed' BJTs are even possible. I did see a depletion type MOSFET that maybe could be used as a negating switch.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with depletion type MOSFETs.  You can get momentary pushbutton switches in DPDT configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I used a wheatstone bridge with transistors, to alow my computer, to control the direction of a small dc motor. The transistor replaced the variable resistor in the bridge. The transistor could have been forward biased with a switch and resistor, instead of a variabl resistor.